# Where to get 'The American Mathematical Monthly' reprints

Tags: reference-works

Is it possible to obtain printed books containing important articles from [The American Mathematical Monthly](http://www.maa.org/publications/periodicals/american-mathematical-monthly) since it started?

Comment: see here http://www.amazon.com/American-Mathematical-Monthly-Classic-Reprint/dp/B00865KPRY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of such a thing.

However, a year ago they (MAA) decided to emphasize the online versions of most journals. For a little extra per year, I also get JSTOR. So, you might get what you want through MAA membership.

Comment: @PeterSheldrick, I'll try to get four items from JSTOR this way, see what happens.

Comment: hmmm. without some specific articles in mind...

Comment: Thank you very much. I will apply as student.